# Finding the last value of a sequence before a termination value C++

Tags: c++, loops, increment

In this loop, x is incremented one too many times.

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 10)
{
    x = x + 3;
}
cout << x;
```

The output for this is 12, when i want it to be 9. Generally speaking, how would I find the last value of a sequence (in this case 9)  given a restraint ( in this case 10).

Comment: Possibly save each value before generating the next one, then when/if the next one violates the constraint, using the stored one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
    int last = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x+=3)
    {
        last = x;
    }
    cout << last;
```

or:

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 10)
{
    x = x + 3;
}
cout << x - 3;
```

or:

```
int x = 0;
int last = 0;
while (x < 10)
{
    last = x;
    x = x + 3;
}
cout << last;
```

or:

```
int x = 0;
while (x + 3 < 10)
{
    x = x + 3;
}
cout << x;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your code you can try:

```
int x = 0;
while (x+3 < 10)
{
    x = x + 3;
}
cout << x;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the last value, it is better to decrease it by the same amount you are incrementing it.

```
int x = 0;
while (x + 3 < 10)
{
x = x + 3;
}
x = x -3;
```

Another way to do this is to use a break statement inside the loop with a suitable condition with which you want to leave it.